# How to include EPS in LuaLaTeX multiple times and have the postscript code run each time?

Tags: luatex, eps, random-numbers, postscript, random

Ahoj,

I have an `.eps` file that does some random number calculations in order to look different on each execution.

Now I want to include it into a LuaLaTeX document several times, and each time it is included the postscript code should be run to make each inclusion look different.

But in fact, when I `\includegraphics` the  `.eps` file several times, each inclusion looks the same.

With a new LuaLaTeX run it looks different, but I want to have each instance of the `.eps` within the same document looking different.

(How) is this achievable?

I now have a working solution with TikZ, but I am still interested if it is possible with EPS.

Here the EPS file in question:

```
%!PS
%%Title: Random dots
%%Pages: 1
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 283 283
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 283.000000 283.000000
%% Page:     1    1

% Copyleft Public Domain

% Save the PostScript environment
save

% Initialise random generator seed
realtime srand

% define dot drawing
/DOT {
  rand 283 mod rand 283 mod
  rand 300 mod 50 div 4 add
  0 360 arc fill
} def

% for loop: Start, step, max.
0 1 40
{
  % for loop pushes the loop variable on the stack, remove it.
  pop
  % Draw dot.
  DOT
} for

% Restore the PostScript environment
restore
showpage

%%Trailer
%%EOF
```

Regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the suffix between two graphics, this will force a new conversion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\epstopdfsetup{suffix=-\SourceExt-converted-to-1} 
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{dots.eps}}

\bigskip


\epstopdfsetup{suffix=-\SourceExt-converted-to-2} 
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{dots.eps}}

\end{document}
```

[image]